# convergence of subsequences of partial sums

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

i am not sure regarding this question. could you help me?

assuming that the two sums, that are obtained from $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n)$ are convergent:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(b_n)=(a_1+a_2)+(a_3+a_4)+...$ ,  $(b_n)=a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}$

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(c_n)=a_1+(a_2+a_3)+(a_4+a_5)+...$, $(c_{n+1}=a_{2n}+a_{2n+1},c_1=a_1$)

I'm asked to prove or disprove the following:

1)$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n)$ is convergent without any additional information.

2)if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(b_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(c_n)=S$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n)$ converges and is equal to S.

3)if $a_n \to 0$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n)$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(b_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(c_n)$

my attempt:

1)$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n)$ converges because the other sums derive from it, and if you change a finite number of elements from it, it will still converge to the same number. so i think it's a true claim even without any additional information.

2)since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(b_n)$ converges, let's call the series of its partial sums S. i.e S=$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(b_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_{2n-1}+a_{2n})$, let's do the same for the third: $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(c_n)=a_1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty(a_{2n}+a_{2n+1})$(because it's $c_{n+1}$ i had to work around it). so if both the sums $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(b_n)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(c_n)$ converge, and as shown they are subsequences of sums originated by changing a finite number of elements, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n)$ must converge to the same sum S.

3)(don't know how to answer it unfortunately), but i do understand it has to do with showing the sums for $s_{2n}$ and $s_{2n+1}$ and showing their limit must be the same, so it will conclude that they converge to the same S.

thank you very much for helping me, stuck on it for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is not very rigorous. These things can be made rigorous.

1. This is wrong. Take $a_k=(-1)^k$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k$ is not convergent, but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k = 0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k=-1$. Check this yourself.
2. This is true.
3. This is also true.

**Proof of (2).** Define the following sequence:
\begin{align}
R_n:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \\
S_n:= \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \\
T_n:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k
\end{align}
You can check the following: 
\begin{align} S_n = R_{2n}, \ \ \text{ and } \ \ T_n = R_{2n+1}\end{align}
You are given the sequence $R_n$ and you know the even subsequence and the odd subsequences converge to the **same** limit. So you know that the original sequence must converge to that limit as well (prove this fact yourself). So $R_n\to S$.

**Proof of (3).**
You know $S_n$ and $T_n$ converge. So for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that for all $n>N$:
\begin{align}
\bigg|\sum_{k=n}^\infty b_k\bigg| < \varepsilon 
\end{align}
Similarly for $\sum_k c_k$. We want to prove the following:
\begin{align}
\bigg | R_n - \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k\bigg|\to 0 \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \bigg | R_n - \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k\bigg|\to 0
\end{align}
Let's do it. There is $N_1$ such that for all $n>N_1$ we have:
\begin{align}
\bigg|\sum_{k=n}^\infty b_k\bigg| < \frac \varepsilon 3  
\end{align}
There is $N_2$ such that for all $n>N_2$ we have $|a_{n}|<\varepsilon/3$ since $a_n\to 0$. 
So:
\begin{align}
\bigg | R_n - \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k\bigg|=
\begin{cases}
\bigg| \sum_{k=1+n/2}^\infty b_k \bigg| & \text{ if } n \text{ is even}\\
\bigg| a_{n+1}+\sum_{k=1+(n+1)/2}^\infty b_k \bigg|& \text{ if } n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
That means:
\begin{align}
\bigg | R_n - \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k\bigg|\leq |a_{n+1}| +\bigg|\sum_{k=1+\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor}^\infty b_k \bigg|+\bigg|\sum_{k=1+\lfloor n/2\rfloor}^\infty b_k \bigg|
\end{align}
Now take $N:=\max\{ 2N_1,N_2\}$, then we have for all $n>N$:
$$\bigg | R_n - \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k\bigg|<3\frac{\varepsilon}{3} =\varepsilon$$
Thus we have shown $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k= \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$$ 
Similarly you can show that $\sum_k a_k=\sum_k c_k$. That one is left for you.